# looping through the current function in R

Tags: r, function

I've generated the following function which performs an operation depending on the range of the input values:

```
foof <- function(height,age){

# we have a choice of two methods to use
# initially set both methods to false
SS = FALSE; # method 1
TT = FALSE; # method 2

# set range for values 
H_rng <- c(0.5,20) # height range
A_rng <- c(0,60) # age range


# check to see if all values lie within the ranges specified
if (isTRUE(all(height<H_rng[1]))){
  SS <- TRUE # use method 1
} else if(!(sum(age<A_rng[1])||sum(age>A_rng[2])) && !(sum(height<H_rng[1]))||sum(height>H_rng[2])){
  TT <- TRUE # use method 2
}


if (SS == TRUE){
  Vals <- SS+TT
}

if (TT == TRUE){
  Vals <- SS-TT
}

return(Vals)

}
```

where the equation used for a specific calculation is dependent on the value of the input array. The function basically looks at all of the values in the input parameter and then if all of these lie within the ranges specified it uses the equations shown to calculate the answer. However, I was wondering how I would alter this to look through each individual value in the input variable and then use the correct equation. This is hard to describe in words so I'll show an example:

```
height <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
height <- matrix(height,nrow = 2)

age <- c(18,9,22,3,4,6,7,32)
age <- matrix(age,nrow = 2)

f <- foof(height,age)
```

This works fine because all of 'height' is below H_rng thus it used method 1.

If I alter this to

```
height <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0)
height <- matrix(height,nrow = 2)

age <- c(18,9,22,3,4,6,7,32)
age <- matrix(age,nrow = 2)

f <- foof(height,age)
```

The function will not return any outputs, which is due to all of the values in height not being less than H_rng.

Therefore, I need to add something like a loop at the end of my function that says if SS and TT are both false then we look at each entry in height and age separately and return the values in an array. I have tried to do this by:

```
foof <- function(height,age){

# initially set both methods to false
SS = FALSE; # method 1
TT = FALSE; # method 2

# set range for values 
H_rng <- c(0.5,20) # height range
A_rng <- c(0,60) # age range


# check to see if all values lie within the ranges specified
if (isTRUE(all(height<H_rng[1]))){
  SS <- TRUE # use method 1
} else if(!(sum(age<A_rng[1])||sum(age>A_rng[2])) && !(sum(height<H_rng[1]))||sum(height>H_rng[2])){
  TT <- TRUE # use method 2
}

if (SS == TRUE){
  Vals <- SS+TT
}

if (TT == TRUE){
  Vals <- SS-TT
}

if (SS == FALSE && TT == FALSE){
  Vals <- 0
  for (i in 1:length(height)){
    Vals[i] <- foof(height[i],age[i])
  }     
}

return(Vals)
```

This generates an output but it does not have the same dimensions as the input variable e.g. here it is a vector whereas the input variable was a matrix. How would I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example , you can add this line before the last line:

```
.....
dim(Vals) <- dim(height)
return(Vals)
```

Comment: or convert Vals to matrix using `matrix` function :)